# Storing range in a cell and using it with Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I need to do vlookup for a range which is variable depending on the date

for example: =Vlookup(a2,http://mypc/[attendance.xlsx]7th March'!$AR:$AS,2,0)

so for the link of the sheet is fine no need to change, but the tab in the sheet it changes according to date:

for example:

if the date is 8/3/2022 the formula will be like this: =Vlookup(a2,http://mypc/[attendance.xlsx]8th March'!$AR:$AS,2,0)

i tried to put the value of the date in a cell and using another vlookup inside the date but it didnt work. i also tried to use indirect formula to recall the sheet link but it didnt work also showing #Ref error.

Btw the lookup value is coming from a table cell.

so any ideas please?

Comment: Will the attendance.xlsx be open, or closed, when you try to use the Vlookup?

Comment: unfortunately it will be closed but the location is inside SharePoint folder accessible anytime.